# Permissions not working on network share

Tags: windows, permissions

I have 1 user which cant access a folder on the network, I have looked in effective permission to see if they have permission to access it and they don’t. This is wired as they should because they are in the same group as someone else how can. Also the group has access.

How do I grant them permission even though they are in the right security group which has access?

Comment: Is the user also in another group which has access explicitly denied?

Comment: How long has the user been a member of the group? Have they logged out and back in since they were added to the group?

Comment: There are no denie properties set for any group or users. User has been a member for a while and previously had access. Yes iv logged them out and restarted the PC.

Comment: How do i deleted this post? Solved by adding the group in "member of" i was doing it in security groups. /redface

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the user explicitly to the permissions list despite them belonging to a group that has access.  I've had this issue before on very large domains where there is a DC lag.